# Raspbian Custom Folder Icons

Tags: raspbian, lxde

I want to change the icons used for different folders on the Raspbian desktop.  Does anyone know if this is possible on the Raspbian LXDE desktop?

Comment: Similar question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/103807/how-can-i-change-the-icon-size-on-lubuntus-desktop

Comment: Similar, but not what I'm trying to do.  This just lets you set the general thumbnail size and icon size.  There has to be a better way to do this for the raspberry PI.

Comment: I believe that you like to specify custom icons. You can specify it by modifying shortcuts .desktop file. Here's an example of what it contains and what every line in it means. http://linux.koolsolutions.com/2009/09/11/howto-place-programs-on-lxde-desktop/ Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Dastaan, interesting, but this is a shortcut.  I Want to change the icon for a folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the appearance of the folders (and the rest of the desktop for that matter) by clicking "Theme and Appearance Settings", under preferences, in the menu. Don't see it? That's OK, sometimes it's hidden. You can un-hide it in the menu editor, or simply run the equivalent command in the terminal:

```
lxappearance
```

You are interested in changing the folder icons, so head over to "Icon theme", like this:

[image]

Each icon theme (on the left) will have a different appearance for the folders.

Comment: To customize the icons, you can poke around in /usr/share/icons and replace the default images with the ones you want.

Answer (score 0):

When I googled this, I was looking for the custom folder icon size to create my own icons for images to display from the menu editor.  This may help someone.

Icon="/path/to/some/128pxX128px.png"

This is as depicted if you were to add a new menu item. Adding a new item prompts you for the path of a 128px square icon.  The line also represents what you would find in an LXDE menu if you were to ever edit one.

Comment: Hello, It's not clear to me how this is supposed to help with the question that was asked. Maybe you can expand a little on where that line goes (i.e. which file; approximate line number or what the default setting is) and what it's supposed to do in relation to changing the folder icons on the LXDE desktop.